# Audio stops playing after rtc is connected

Tags: arduino-nano, sd-card, audio, rtc, tmrpcm

I am trying to play a song using arduino while at the same time display time using a rtc board using the tmrpcm library. However, if the rtc board is connected no sound is played.

I do understand that the tmrpcm may be interfering with the wire.h library but even commenting the same doesn't resolve the problem.

I am using the following code:

```
// Date and time functions using a DS1307 RTC connected via I2C and Wire lib
#include <RTClib.h>
#include<Wire.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "SevenSegmentTM1637.h"
#include "SevenSegmentExtended.h"
#include "SevenSegmentFun.h"
#include "SD.h"
#define SD_ChipSelectPin 4
#include "TMRpcm.h"
#include "SPI.h"

TMRpcm tmrpcm;

const int ProxSensor=3;
int inputVal = 0;
#define CLK 8
#define DIO 7

// The amount of time (in milliseconds) between tests
#define TEST_DELAY   2000

SevenSegmentFun    display(CLK, DIO);

RTC_DS1307 rtc;

char daysOfTheWeek[7][12] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

void setup () {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  if(!SD.begin(SD_ChipSelectPin))
  {
    Serial.println("SD fail");
    return;
  }
  while (!Serial); // for Leonardo/Micro/Zero
  tmrpcm.speakerPin=9;
  Serial.begin(57600);
  if (! rtc.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
    while (1);
  }

  if (! rtc.isrunning()) {
    Serial.println("RTC is NOT running!");
    // following line sets the RTC to the date & time this sketch was compiled
    rtc.adjust(DateTime(2019, 10, 19, 01,41,00));
    // This line sets the RTC with an explicit date & time, for example to set
    // January 21, 2014 at 3am you would call:
    // rtc.adjust(DateTime(2014, 1, 21, 3, 0, 0));
  }
  pinMode(ProxSensor,INPUT);    //Pin 2 is connected to the output of proximity sensor
  display.begin();
}

void loop(){
  DateTime now = rtc.now();
  display.print((now.unixtime() / 86400L )-17963);
  Serial.print((now.unixtime() / 86400L )-17963);
  while(digitalRead(ProxSensor)==LOW)      //Check the sensor output
  {
    tmrpcm.setVolume(5);
    tmrpcm.play("test.wav");
      repeat:
    if(digitalRead(ProxSensor==LOW))
      goto repeat;
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TMRpcm and one of your other libraries might use the same timer on Uno which causes one of them to break. Either get a Arduino Mega which can run TMRpcm on TIMER3,4 or 5 or use libraries that don't require a timer.

Comment: In what way does the Wire library use a timer?

Comment: @Majenko probably for timing the SCK pulses.

Comment: I can't find any reference of what it is used for and if used at all but it seems that the usage of the TWBR breaks many things related to timer one.

Comment: Can you cite some evidence for this? This is new to me - and the TWI peripheral has nothing to do with any timer peripherals - the baud rate generator is internal to TWI and uses the system clock as its source.

Comment: @SoumendraDey, explain please how did this answer help, because it should not

Answer (score 2):

The problem is

```
repeat:
if(digitalRead(ProxSensor==LOW))
  goto repeat;
```

`ProxSensor==LOW` is false so 0. **you read the pin 0** and the outcome is random. The surrounding wiring can affect that. If digitalRead(0) is zero the wav starts playing immediately again. At least use

```
while (digitalRead(ProxSensor) == LOW);
```

Comment: I am already using while (digitalRead(ProxSensor) == LOW) in my code

Comment: @SoumendraDey,  read the answer again and slow